# JavaScript modules are not loading

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, liveserver, npm-live-server

I am trying to import a module to my JavaScript code, which should later run on a WordPress server.
Currently i wanted to test it on localhost, but it gives me an error like:
`The Skript from "http://127.0.0.1:46513/js/main.js" was loaded, despite it's MIME-Typ ("text/html") is not valid in JavaScript`
Which is strange because it is js code and not html.
My main.js looks like this:

`const { Origin, Horoscope } = require('./circular-natal-horoscope-js/dist/index.js');`

And index.html like this:

```
<html>
  <head> Horoscope </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried different import syntax:
`import { Origin, Horoscope } from '/circular-natal-horoscope-js/dist/index.js';`
Which gives me the same error.

The only thing which is working is, when i type in `node main.js` into console, then the Origin and Horoscope functions are beeing loaded.

How can i use this to be working in my js-files without using the console?

Comment: The problem is not with those files, but with whatever server you are using at `http://127.0.0.1:46513` which serves them with incorrect http headers

Comment: I started the server with ```npx live-server index.html```, because on lampp-localhost it wasn't working. (I forgot to mention this).
How can i set the headers for the server? On WordPress there is a textfield to do so i think, but i would like to test it before i upgrade my webhosting to have nodejs access...

Comment: I don't see why you would need nodejs for anything. To properly test, run a clone of your Wordpress setup locally.

Comment: Looks like [a bug (or "missing feature") of that `live-server` package](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/230) you're using. Lot's of other people have complained as well. This will not affect your production Wordpress environment.

Comment: The horoscope lbrary uses the ```module.exoport()``` syntax, which i though was only for NodeJs, or atleast not for my lampp/localhost environment, because it says "module is not defined".
But i will try to clone it and see if it works with NodeJs locally, before i upgrade my hosting-plan, thank you for the hint and also the link!

Comment: but how can i do this without NodeJS?